# Post Form data into multiple urls on one button click

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jsp

Is it possible to Post form data into two different Urls like

```
<form action="https://xyz.aspx;https://abc.php;" method='POST'  onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this)">

</form>
```

I want to post form data into two different action (urls) .
How can i do ?

Comment: use two ajax calls.......its better.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JQuery so you can utilise the Jquery Ajax function to send two different requests, containing same data.

Why don't you use ajax for this. It will help you to send 2 requests to 2 different pages.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url : "form.php",
       data: {'field1':field1,'field2':field2},
       success: function(msg){
             // get response here  
           }
       });

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url : "display.php",
       data: {'field1':field1,'field2':field2},
       success: function(msg){
             // get response here  
           }
       });
```

Thanks,
JFIT

Answer (score 0):

use ajax:

```
$.post( "https://xyz.aspx", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
$.post( "https://abc.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
```

make a function whit this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using the form action atribute and splitting the urls;

```
$("form").submit(function(){

    var actions = $(this).attr("action").split(";"),
        formData = $(this).serialize();

    actions.pop();//discard empty

    $.each(actions, function( index, value ) {
      $.post( value, formData  );
    });

    return false;

});
```